# Prove: $(a+b+c)\frac{2+\sqrt{abc}\left(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}\right)}{1+\sqrt{abc}\left(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}\right)}+2\sum{\sqrt{ab}}\ge6$

Tags: inequality

Prove that the following inequality: $$(a+b+c)\frac{2+\sqrt{abc}\left(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}\right)}{1+\sqrt{abc}\left(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}\right)}+2\left(\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{bc}+\sqrt{ca}\right)\ge6$$ holds for all non-negative real numbers such that: $ab+bc+ca=1.$

The problem is stronger than: $a+b+c+\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{bc}+\sqrt{ca}\ge3$ which is also hard to me.

I used pqr method. Set $(a,b,c)=(x^2,y^2,z^2)$, then:

$(xy)^2+(yz)^2+(zx)^2=1$ implies that: $r=\dfrac{q^2-1}{2p}$. Hence, we need to prove that: $$(p^2-2q)\frac{q^2+3}{1+q^2}+2q\ge6$$ and I don't know how to full it.

Is there any idea to help me get full solution? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Anyone help me solve this?

Comment: It is really hard